# want to create a collection view in swift3

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to create uicollectionview with the expandable format. 
When we tap on the expandable cell that more in the section cells should be loaded. After taping again close the section.
It is like expanding and collapsing sections.
Both section cell and inner cell are dynamic.

Comment: please check these 
https://github.com/apploft/APLExpandableCollectionView

And
 https://www.raywenderlich.com/99087/swift-expanding-cells-ios-collection-views

Comment: This is for UITableView I want to do this in UICollectionView

Comment: Did you check these examples? they files!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something like this.

Make a structure like this globally so that you can access these in //your table methods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var tblView: UITableView!
    let arr = [ "dict1":["1":"one","2":"two"],
                "dict2":["3":"three","2":"four"],
    ] as [String : Any]
    var arrDict = [[String:AnyObject]]()
    var aDict1 = [String:Any]()
    var aDict2 = [String:Any]()
    var aDict3 = [String:Any]()
    var isbuttonTappedForExpand = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        aDict1 = ["Tittle": "Quick Start",
                      "RowKey": "0",
                      "ValueKey": ["Section0 row0",
                                        "Section0 row1",
                                        "Section0 row2",
                                       ]
                      ] as [String : Any]

        aDict2 = ["Tittle": "Personal",
                      "RowKey": "0",
                      "ValueKey": ["Section0 row1",
                                        "Section1 row1",
                                        "Section1 row2",
                                        ]
                     ] as [String : Any]

       aDict3 = ["Tittle": "Business",
                      "RowKey": "0",
                      "ValueKey": ["Section0 row2",
                                          "Section2 row1",
                                          "Section2 row2",
                                        ]
                    ] as [String : Any]

        arrDict.append(aDict1 as [String : AnyObject])
        arrDict.append(aDict2 as [String : AnyObject])
        arrDict.append(aDict3 as [String : AnyObject])

        print("Array of dictionaries is\(arrDict)")
        print([arr ])
        print( arrDict[0]["Tittle"] ?? 2)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

//Then pass your data into tableview delegate methods


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return arrDict.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (arrDict[section]["RowKey"] as? String == "0"){
        return 0
    }
        else{
            return arrDict.count
            }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell:CustomTableViewCell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
        let arr = arrDict[indexPath.row]["ValueKey"] as! [String]
        cell.btnClickAddMore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{

        return 100
    }

//you will have to add sections first after clicking on sections you will get your cell so here you will make your view for section


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){

        view.tintColor = UIColor .black

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?  {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tblView.frame.size.width, height: 100)
        let headerView = UIView(frame:rect)
        headerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SectionView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! SectionViewClass
        view.btnClickAdd.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.btnClickAdd.tag = section
        view.btnClickAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.frame = headerView.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        headerView.addSubview(view)
        return headerView
    }

    func pressButton(button: UIButton) {

        if (arrDict[button.tag]["RowKey"] as? String == "0") {

            arrDict[button.tag]["RowKey"] = "1" as AnyObject?

        }
        else if (arrDict[button.tag]["RowKey"] as? String == "1") {

             arrDict[button.tag]["RowKey"] = "0" as AnyObject?

        }
        tblView .reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your solution is for UITableView. I want this for UICollectionView.

Comment: you can do the same for collectionview.main thing here is the structure.you can use collection view methods here instead of uitableview datasource methods.I can provide you with a demo if you need.

Comment: Yes please give

Comment: Yes, see I want something like this check the link https://github.com/johntvolk/ExpandableColumnLayout/blob/master/demo.gif

Comment: see if you want something like this then you can go with tableview too.is is compulsory for you to use collectionview here?

Comment: Yes CollectionView is compulsory

Comment: yeah ok then m making a demo will share with you soon.

Comment: Are you creating a demo?

Comment: See this tutorial for creating collection views. This site is for solving specific problems, not tutorials: https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started